# Instantiating single thread once only from django view

Tags: python, django, multithreading, python-multithreading, modbus

I want to know if there is a way to only instantiate a daemon thread once in my django view(kind of like a singleton approach) and manage it(stop/start anytime)

In my django web application I made an admin page where all my devices(sensors) are displayed with a checkbox. The checkbox is bascially just updating the DB to set the "isLogging" field to true or false

```
views.py
def devices(request):
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    devices = TDevices.objects.all()

    if request.method == "POST":
        for device in devices:
            if "device_" + str(device.ixDevice) in request.POST:
                device.bIsLogging = True
                device.save()
            else:
                device.bIsLogging = False
                device.save()

    ping_sensor() #thread target function

    return render(request, 'devices.html' , context_instance = RequestContext(request, { 'title':'Device Management', 'devices': TDevices.objects.all()}))
```

When my thread starts I want it to run continuously  in the background where it will query the db every 5 minutes and check which devices are enabled, then ping that device for data while the user can go and do other things.

```
thread target function
def ping_sensor():
    #query db for enabled devices
    for device in TDevices.objects.all():
        if device.bIsLogging:
            print "ping : " + device.deviceName
```

The problem I'm struggling with is how can I create a thread only once and manage it(stop/start it anytime) since the way I have it setup now it will always create new threads anytime the view is called

Comment: Did you consider using a cronjob for this? This is a different approach but would be easy to setup and handle.

Comment: a cronjob? Don't know anything about it. I was just looking into celery.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron, it is simpler than celery.

Comment: i just looked at it and it seems to be exactly the thing I'm looking for